# Gradle fileTree exclude all except certain directories

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using the fileTree utility to get a list of files but need to exclude all directories except a select few from the list.

My directory structure:

```
node_modules/
    react-native/
    react/
    third-party-package/
    another-package/
```

I need to exclude all directories except the ones named react-native and react.

Currently I am excluding all node_modules, but this is not what I want...

`fileTree(dir: '.', excludes: [ 'node_modules/**'] )`

How would I do this with the fileTree?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a closure for this. Something like this:

```
fileTree(dir: '.').exclude {details ->
    (details.file.canonicalPath.contains("node_modules")
            && !details.file.canonicalPath.contains('react'))}
```

You can provide your own condition for files, you want to exlude. Here is a simpliest one, where the files paths are checked, whether they contain `node_modules` and not `react` and if condition is true, this files are excluded.

Sure, you have to make it more specific, but you are free to provide any condition for you requirements.